# Building a Days Counter with Arduino Leonardo and an RTC 3231

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, real-time-clock

I've been trying to create a days counter that starts counting from a unix timestamp. I'm using an arduino Leonardo, an RTC DS 3231 and a 7-segment serial display(by microbot). Here's the display link: [Serial Display Link](https://www.microbot.it/en/product/137/4-Digit-Serial-LED-Display-BLUE-digit.html)

But I cannot get the display to print ny output. I think I might have messed up with the connections.

I have connected the Vcc and Gnd from the rtc to the 3.3v and gnd of the arduino and the Sda and Scl to the Sda and Scl of the arduino.

For the display I connected the Vcc to the 5V, the gnd to the gnd and the Rx to the digital output 5( Is this correct? I know I have messed up sth here)

Here is the code:

```
#include <Time.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_LEDBackpack.h"
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS1307 rtc = RTC_DS1307();

Adafruit_7segment clockDisplay = Adafruit_7segment();

int hours = 0;
int minutes = 0;
int seconds = 0;

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last millis event time 
unsigned long sensorpreviousMillis = 0;        // will store last millis event time 
unsigned long fiveMinuteInterval = 300000;           // interval at which to use event time (milliseconds)
unsigned long postDaysInterval = 7200000 ; //seconds in a day 86400000

#define DISPLAY_ADDRESS   0x70

unsigned long theDateWeGotTogether = 1441843200;  //in unixtime
unsigned long days ; 
int weeks ; 

void setup() {                
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  clockDisplay.begin(DISPLAY_ADDRESS);
  rtc.begin();

 bool setClockTime = !rtc.isrunning();
 if (setClockTime) {
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
  }
}

void loop() {
//  DateTime now = rtc.now(); 

   days = ((now() - theDateWeGotTogether) / 86400); //86400 is the number of seconds in a day 
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  ShowDaysReading();
  time_t t = now();

  if(currentMillis - sensorpreviousMillis > fiveMinuteInterval) 
  {
    // save the last time you performed event
    sensorpreviousMillis = currentMillis;   
    DateTime Zeit = rtc.now();
  }
}

void ShowDaysReading()
{  
  days = ((now() - theDateWeGotTogether) / 86400); //86400 number of seconds in a day
  weeks = ((now() - theDateWeGotTogether) / (86400 * 7) ); //86400 number of seconds in a day

  clockDisplay.print(days); 
}
```

Comment: We can start by debugging this from the ground up. Have you tested the display with an example code or had it working before you implemented your own code? It might just be a bad display.

Comment: The display works. It just outputs 0000. I am building this for Valentine's Day for my girlfriend. And the timestamp is when we got together. Thank you so much for trying to help :)

Comment: Absolutely, this seems like a great project. I really want this to work for you :) So, I took a look at the code from the DS 3231 library. Looks like you need to call Wire.begin(); to start the i2c interface. And if you are using the serial output, you need to call Serial.begin(9600);

Comment: So I made those changes but again the display outputs 0000 and not the 4 digit number I want. In the arduino forum(where people are not so frinedly) one just commented: "The code points to using an I2C Based backpack. No idea where you got connecting the unit to pin 5 from." But I do not really understand what does this mean.

Comment: Yeah, people here can be just as bad. Anyways, a backpack is a board that is usually soldered onto the back of an LCD pinout to convert signals to/from the I2C interface. Is the RTC DS 323 using the backpack header file? If not, I think it would be easier to approach this differently. Hopefully someone else will come in to see if there's any way to make it work with what you included though.

Comment: Here are the serial display an the rtc: https://imgur.com/gallery/W73aQ